# Examples of algorithms best their class that require cyclical data structures

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

I remember that the [Roc Lang](https://www.roc-lang.org/) website claimed that their choice to forbid any form of cyclic data structures prohibited their customer to implement some of the best in their class algorithms, id est some algorithms that are better than everything else solving the problem that they are designed to solve.

I have tried in some trivial manners to find some algorithm which as described by Roc lang is the best in their class but cannot be implemented in Roc Lang given the choice to forbid any kind of cyclic data structures which includes double linked lists, graphs with cycles, arbitrary acyclic directed graph and more; have been unable to find any example of such algorithms.

Can please you give examples of some algorithms?

Answer (score -1):

Any graph algorithm that works on general graphs (i.e., is not restricted to acyclic graphs) qualifies.  You should be able to look through your favorite textbook and find many algorithms that work on graphs.

For instance, you could consider shortest-path algorithms.

Comment: Depth First Search is in the texbook “Introduction to Algorithms” by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, and Clifford Stein are you sure that of you claim?

Comment: @Delfin, I don't understand what your comment is trying to say, but it sounds like you are aware of another example that answers your own question -- great!